# unity 5.3.0f4 error CS0029;cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please help, i'm currently working on a brick breaker game and working on paddle script
but it shows error on line 17, i don't know how to change float to vector3

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0.5f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);

        float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition / Screen.width * 16;

        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, 0.5f, 15.5f);

        this.transform.position = paddlePos;
    }
}
```

here is the script combined both answers

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

```
    Vector3 mousePosInBlocks;
    Vector3 paddlePos;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    paddlePos = new Vector3 (0.5f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);

    mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition / Screen.width * 16;

    paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks.x, 0.5f, 15.5f);

    this.transform.position = paddlePos;
}
```

}

Comment: thank you both answers, finally works

Answer (score 3):

Your error occurs at this line (I guess?):

```
float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition / Screen.width * 16;
```

The problem is exactly, what the error message tells you: `Input.mousePosition` is a `Vector3`. If you divide a `Vector3` by some float, the result is also a `Vector3` as this is an element-wise division. As it is still a `Vector3` you cannot assign it to a `float` variable.

To solve this you should either make `mousePosInBlocks` a `Vector3` or choose a component of the vector to assign.

Reference: [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html)

Answer (score 2):

Mathf.Clamp needs a float, not a Vector3.

Change this :

```
 paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, 0.5f, 15.5f);
```

To :

```
paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks.x, 0.5f, 15.5f);
```

Same thing for y if needed.

You also need to make mousePosInBlocks a Vector3.

If you only want to process x, keep mousePosInBlocks as a float but replace `Input.mousePosition` by `Input.mousePosition.x`